# Error in setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, : could not find function "setup_twitter_oauth"

Tags: r, twitter, oauth, installation, package

After installing the following on rstudio:

```
install.packages("twitteR")
install.packages("ROAuth")
library(RCurl)
install.packages("base64inc")
```

When I try to setup_twitter_oauth i get as a result this:

> Error in setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret,  : 
>     could not find function "setup_twitter_oauth"

What to do?
Thanks for any real help.

Comment: did you set yourself up on Twitter as an account, thereby generating the four codes you need?  Did you also call library(twitterR) and library(ROAuth)?  You can't just install the packages.

Comment: yes,i did it. set up the account dev, get the 4 keys and downloaded the library

Comment: But still the same Error appears

Comment: To get the most help on SO, include all the code you ran that led to the error.  That way people can reproduce your error and give better advice.

Comment: Ok, this it's the code i run on rstudio:

Comment: install.packages("twitteR") #installs TwitteR library (twitteR) #loads TwitteR

Comment: pi_key <- "" #in the quotes, put your API key api_secret <- "" #in the quotes, put your API secret token token <- "" #in the quotes, put your token token_secret <- "" #in the quotes, put your token secret

Comment: setup_twitter_oauth(api_key, api_secret, token, token_secret)

Comment: And after that i get the error as in the title:  Error in setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, : could not find function "setup_twitter_oauth"

Comment: Alex, edit your question to include the code you used, so people can read it easily.